# RTAI installation into arm-9 with 3.4 kernel version

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm, rtai

I want to configure RTAI for ARM9, I have hummingbird board which have 3.4 linux kernel version.
As I read different thread then i am understand that there is only linux 2.6 installation document available for ARM.
Please help me for this.

Comment: For the ARM architecture I suggest you to switch to Xenomai rather than RTAI.

Comment: RTAI performance is far better then xenomai as per others research.

Comment: For sure it is on x86. Not very sure about other architectures.

Comment: Well, the front page of [what I assume is the right website](https://www.rtai.org/?Homepage) says "kernel support up to 3.18.22" - what exactly is the [practical, answerable problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you're having with installing it, because "I read something somewhere. Please help me" isn't even a question...

Comment: If you don't have any idea about this question then leave it, don,t criticize